# TreeView - can't insert the data in correct places

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, model-view-controller

I need to add some values from database into the TreeView. The thing is when I call the for loop, I can add the values into specific columns, but some of columns becomes blank. For example let's say I have a TreeView with three columns:

Name, surname, age

When I call the for loop for name, it will insert data in name column, but when I will call another loop for surname, rest of the rows from name are blank. After all data from name will be displayed in first column, then another loop will insert data from surname, but the name column will be blank. How I may fix it?

Here's some code:

```
    self.tree_view_test = ttk.Treeview(frame, selectmode="browse")
    self.tree_view_test.pack()

    self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree_view_test.yview())
    self.scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='x')

    self.tree_view_test.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.tree_view_test["columns"] = ("name", "surname", "age")
    self.tree_view_test["show"] = "headings"

    self.tree_view_test.column("name", width=90, anchor='se')
    self.tree_view_test.column("surname", width=90, anchor='se')
    self.tree_view_test.column("age", width=90, anchor='se')

    self.tree_view_test.heading("name", text="Name")
    self.tree_view_test.heading("surname", text="Surname")
    self.tree_view_test.heading("age", text="Age")


    def retrieve_employees_data(self):
    self.controller.get_employees_name()
    self.controller.get_employees_surname()



    test_dict = {}

    for i in self.name_tuple:
        self.tree_view_test.insert("", 1, values=i)
    for j in self.surname_tuple:
        self.tree_view_test.insert("", 0, values=("",j))
```

Comment: You cannot insert to two columns separately.  All values in a row should be inserted at the same time.  However you can use `.set()` to update a particular cell.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How I should approach it then?

Comment: Try `for item in zip(self.name_tuple, self.surname_tuple): self.tree_view_test.insert("", "end", values=item)`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @acw1668 Post that as answer then